# Dell Studio 1558 working only on external monitor

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

First of all let me make this clear it's not a problem with the Laptop's LCD, I tried the display test, pressing 'D' during power on and the display was working, it showed the colors, etc.

**System Specifications:-**

- Intel Corei3 m370 Processor
- ATI Radeon 5470 Graphics Card
- Full HD Display
- 4 GB Ram
- Windows 7 Professional

**Issues:-**

- If I install ATI Graphics card driver, windows boots but in the final stage of booting windows shows the blue screen mentioning some error message about the graphics card and restarts.
- If I don't install any graphics driver manually then windows boots and works properly but displays only on an external 15 Inch monitor, the laptop's display remains blank, also the graphics card used is the Intel Corei3 Graphics and not the ATI Radeon graphics and in the graphics properties it shows STANDARD VGA Adapter.

**Troubleshooting:-**

- There was heating issue before and pc wouldn't start so purchased a brand new heatsink to fix the heating issue and so the heating issue is solved at least for the processor may be the graphics card is still overheating.
- Did a fresh installation of Windows 7 Professional to make sure there are no viruses or other programs creating this problem.
- The Laptop's display is fine, I tried the display test by pressing 'D' on power on and the display showed the colors, etc no problem with the display.
- I read in a forum in which someone who was facing exactly this problem and ran the Dell Diagnostic and it solved the issue temporarily, I tried it too but didn't work for me.

**Need Help Regarding**

- I'm not interested in getting the ATI Radeon to work, I'm okay with the Corei3's graphics but I just want the laptop's display to work, I don't want to use an external monitor. So please provide any troubleshooting tips that I haven't followed yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been more than 2 years since I posted this issue and would like to give update. Right before the laptop stopped working, the fan was working at full speed, so this is a overheating issue. If your laptop stops working because of this, the best thing to do is to remove the heat sinks from the graphics card and processor and apply a good thermal paste as well as buy new rubber pads for the 2 Chips (Graphic Card RAM I think), after I did this my laptop did work but if I installed the graphic card driver then I would face the same issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Core i5 and Radeon 5650. Can you get the laptop screen to display in Safe Mode? Solution for me was to boot in Safe Mode without the external monitor plugged in.  Completely uninstall the ATI drivers (just leaving the integrated Intel graphics). Reboot normally. All good since then. I think it may have been a clash between the two sets of drivers?? Started happening straight after a recent windows update. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mark, even in safe mode only the external monitor works, I mean the laptop doesn't even display the Dell Logo on startup it stays blank from the start, I did a clean Windows 7 Install 2 times, formatting the C partition but still no luck. I checked the display by pressing Function+D and it showed all the colors, so display is good. What did work for me once was setting the Power Option to Maximum Performance and when I restarted the laptop display worked but after few minutes of usage the pc freezed.

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is working using the BIST test, it means that the LCD is fine, disconnect and reconnect the lcd connector cable(the one which connects the lcd to the motherboard). If the problem isnt solved, you will have to replace the lcd connector cable. All the best.